# Offset div based on image width

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to offset the  element containing the image which has 21 frames. 0 - 21. I've placed 21 vertical columns over the image to visualize which frame should be present when the user's cursor is within the column lines. So each time your cursor moves into a different column of the grid, it should display a new frame. I need help figuring out whey the last frame (20) only shows when the user's cursor is on the very last pixel to the far right of the frame?

All the work is done in the javascript. I've commented each step and print to the console useful information regarding the math.

[image: ,]

https://jsfiddle.net/JokerMartini/2e9awc4u/67/

```js
window.onload = function() {
  console.log('go')

  $("#viewport").mousemove(function(e) {
    // step 0: value to offset each frame (without scale)
    const frameWidth = 320
    // step 1: get the current mouse position in relation to the current element
    const x = e.offsetX
    // step 3: get width of viewable content, subtract 1 pixel starts at 0px
    const viewWidth = $("#viewport").width() - 1
    // step 4: find the % of the current position (in decimals 0-1.0)
    const percent = x / viewWidth
    // step 5: find the frame by the current percentage
    const filmstripWidth = $("#filmstrip").width()
    const frameByPercent = Math.round((filmstripWidth - frameWidth) * percent)
    // step 6: find the nearest multiplier to frameWidth to offset
    const offset = Math.floor(frameByPercent / frameWidth) * frameWidth
    // const offset = -frameByPercent // smooth
    // step 7: set that as the current position in negative (for offset reasons)
    $("#filmstrip").css('transform', 'translate(' + -offset + 'px)')
    
    console.log(
      'CURSOR:', x,
      'VIEW:', viewWidth,
      'PERCENT:', percent,
      'IMAGE WIDTH:', filmstripWidth,
      frameByPercent
    )
  });

};
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#filmstrip {
  will-change: transform;
  pointer-events:none;
}

#margin-center {
  background: grey;
  padding: 30px
}

#viewport {
  height: 180px;
  width: 320px;
  background: #FFFFAA;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden; /* Comment for debugging */
}

#guides {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events:none;
}

#content {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <div id="margin-center">
    <div id='viewport'>
    <img id='filmstrip' src="https://i.ibb.co/7XDpcnd/timer.jpg" width="auto" height="180">
      <svg id="guides" width="320px" height="180px">
        <defs>
          <pattern id="grid" width="15.238" height="180" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <path d="M 16 0 L 0 0 0 180" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
          </pattern>
        </defs>

        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#grid)" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with the # of columns. If you hover over say frame 9, you'll notice that it doesn't toggle on the left edge exactly, but rather about halfway across. Each new frame's left edge is shifted slightly further right compared to the previous frame. Also you mention there are 21 frames, but then you mention indices 0-21... shouldn't that be 0-20?

Comment: these are all problems ive come across and im not sure how to fix it

Comment: Not directly related but helpful: for efficiency, you should define your _constants_ (values which don't change depending on the mouse position) outside of the `mousemove` function, and only set _variables_ (values that change depending on the mouse position) inside of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your results are offset by 1 because you deducted one full frameWidth.
Added code to cap percent at 0.999, to prevent it jumping to 22nd frame.  mousemove positions will sometimes be at end position or greater.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  console.log('go')

  $("#viewport").mousemove(function(e) {
    // step 0: value to offset each frame (without scale)
    const frameWidth = 320
    // step 1: get the current mouse position in relation to the current element
    const x = e.offsetX
    // step 3: get width of viewable content, subtract 1 pixel starts at 0px
    const viewWidth = $("#viewport").width() - 1
    // step 4: find the % of the current position (in decimals 0-1.0)
    const percent = x / viewWidth
    // step 5: find the frame by the current percentage
    const filmstripWidth = $("#filmstrip").width()
    const frameByPercent = Math.round((filmstripWidth) * Math.min(percent,0.999))
    // step 6: find the nearest multiplier to frameWidth to offset
    const offset = Math.floor(frameByPercent / frameWidth) * frameWidth
    // const offset = -frameByPercent // smooth
    // step 7: set that as the current position in negative (for offset reasons)
    $("#filmstrip").css('transform', 'translate(' + -offset + 'px)')
    
    console.log(
      'CURSOR:', x,
      'VIEW:', viewWidth,
      'PERCENT:', percent,
      'IMAGE WIDTH:', filmstripWidth,
      frameByPercent
    )
  });

};
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#filmstrip {
  will-change: transform;
  pointer-events:none;
}

#margin-center {
  background: grey;
  padding: 30px
}

#viewport {
  height: 180px;
  width: 320px;
  background: #FFFFAA;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden; /* Comment for debugging */
}

#guides {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events:none;
}

#content {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <div id="margin-center">
    <div id='viewport'>
    <img id='filmstrip' src="https://i.ibb.co/7XDpcnd/timer.jpg" width="auto" height="180">
      <svg id="guides" width="320px" height="180px">
        <defs>
          <pattern id="grid" width="15.238" height="180" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <path d="M 16 0 L 0 0 0 180" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
          </pattern>
        </defs>

        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#grid)" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: i thought i need to do that since the width is 0 - 319

Comment: You'll have to deal with it using "21", which doesn't exist in your filmstrip, at the end, if it being blank isn't your intended behavior.  Your code basically was equivalent to doing:  `position = (total - countSize) / countSize`  equivalent to "total/countSize - 1", whereas what you really wanted was just position = totalspace / spacesize

Comment: This works better bug bugs out when you hit 1.0 on the percent

Comment: But there are 21 frames in the image? if you include 0. So how would you suggest i fix the code then?

Comment: It's 0-indexed, going past the end is equivalent to going to the 22nd frame.

Comment: but in my case im not going past the last frame. im doing 1.0

Comment: I was able to fix it by removing the -1 from the width and implementing your change. that way the percent never reaches 1.0 only 0.999

Comment: I was investigating to make sure there weren't any other problems.  Some of the calculations are redundant, but mostly harmless.  Note that -1 pixel might not be enough to guarantee it won't get to 1.0, because there will be mousemove offset values that are larger than the viewport width (thus > 1.0).  Move your mouse over the end gradually but quickly and you will see it still flashes the blank frame.  You'll still have to round the percent down below 1.0 in the end, unless you don't expect that edge case to pop up in normal use

Comment: What would be redundant that we could reduce ?